# Stack overflow error in Report document Crystal Report

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

Having this error while initializing ReportDocument:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

[image]

Comment: Can you post the stack trace? And the method being called? Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: My bad, I was calling the same block of code multiple time, moved the code to a new function problem solved.